# Mouse right-click menu in RXVT

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal, urxvt, rxvt

I moved from gnome-terminal to urxvt. I am used to having a right-click menu in gnome-terminal. Do such menus exist in urxvt?

Comment: I don't believe so, rxvt is a pretty minimal terminal emulator. If you want to split your terminal up and do more in one terminal, you should look into a terminal multiplexer like tmux or screen.

Answer (score 3):

No, rxvt is not that kind of terminal emulator. You might find Sakura pleasing.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, in that rxvt does have an option menu, but it is very correct that Sakura is pleasing.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know gnome-terminal menus, but urxvt have the ctrl+right click. You may need to select some text and AFAIK, those menu entries can be configured

If you are looking for copy&paste, there aren't any, but you can copy&paste using the X11 way, by selecting the text (and keep it selected) and paste with middle click. You can also use ctrl+delete and shift+insert if you prefer using the keys for the copy&paste.

Notice that linux have 2 (or even 3) clipboards, depending of the copy&paste method used, so to make your life easier, i recommend a clipboad manager that can sync then. I use Parcellite, but you have many more: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Managers

Comment: by the way, ctrl+middle click open the "option" menu

Answer (score 0):

For Copy / Paste using right click in rxvt

Edit file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/urxvt/perl/selection-popup

(where is it? use: find /usr -name selection-popup )

Search for this sub code and change lines:

```
sub on_button_press {
   my ($self, $event) = @_;

   if ($event->{button} == 3 ) {
     my $popup = $self->popup ($event)
       or return 1;

    $self->selection_request (urxvt::CurrentTime, 1);
    return 1;

    $popup->add_title ("Selection");
    my $text = $self->selection;
    ...
```

Don't forget to enable the perl extension,
edit file ~/.Xdefaults, and add:
URxvt.perl-ext-common: selection-popup

enjoy... VLDSoft

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).